# Scout Eclipse Server - Client communication

Tags: client-server, communication, eclipse-scout

I know how to make communication in client -> service direction, but I need communication in direction service -> client. I would need some observer on client or some way that I can call client from server.

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Client Notifications](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Client_Notification) for that. Check the [client notification how-to page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/HowTo/4.0/Client_notifications) for a raw description of what you need to add to your application.

I never used them myself. Be aware that they are not a solution for all use cases.